# Download Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can anybody tell me the site from which I can download Visual Studio 2008? Because Visual Studio 2010 is now able to be purchased I can't find Studio 2008.

Comment: (1) There is an express version of 2010 too. (2) Google?

Comment: This is off-topic... if you can't get it from MS, you probably can't get it.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Express (free) version of Visual Studio 2008 SP1 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13276).(requires Visual Studio 2008 that a trial can be downloaded [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso)!

Links updated

Comment: those links don't work anymore, afaik

Comment: @Jsz, you're right, apparently they were discontinued, but the SP1 version is still downloadable. I updated the link. (The link you provided works, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't seem to want you do use VS2008 anymore. Here are some currently valid links (for express), though.

web installers:

VB express 2008:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/c/3/dc3439e7-5533-4f4c-9ba0-8577685b6e7e/vbsetup.exe

C# express 2008:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/c/3/dc3439e7-5533-4f4c-9ba0-8577685b6e7e/vcssetup.exe

C++ express 2008:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/c/3/dc3439e7-5533-4f4c-9ba0-8577685b6e7e/vcsetup.exe

web developer express 2008:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/c/3/dc3439e7-5533-4f4c-9ba0-8577685b6e7e/vnssetup.exe

Note that the registration page for VS2008 404's. To get around this, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540370/2844375).

Answer (score 2):

Old thread...but i fell on it on my search:

Direct download link:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso

credit to:

[download and install visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108102/download-and-install-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 1):

You can go on here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a22341ee-21db-43aa-8431-40be78461ee0

And grab the web installer according to what version you want:

vbsetup.exe - for visual basic

vcsetup.exe - for c/c++

.

.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a subscriber to MSDN you will find 2003,2005 and 2008 versions available in the downloads section.